# Yellow lemon tree leaves and fruit dropping

Tags: plant-health, plant-care, leaves, watering, lemons

[image]So it’s summertime and I know that lemon trees should be growing fruit. My young tree has been struggling of late with these yellow leaves for while now and it’s dropping a lot of its young fruit. It’s starting to get brown spots and chlorides as well. I’ve fertilized it and it’s in full sun most of the day and I water it. It doesn’t react well after watering. Is it being overwatered? Do I need to do anything to help it revive?

Comment: What did you fertilize with?  Do you use filtered or tap water?

Comment: How are you and how much are you watering it? Are there drainage holes at the bottom? When you water  does the water gets soaked up immediately?

Comment: I use Dr. Earth Organic fruit tree fertilizer and tap water. Drainage holes are at the bottom. Might take a few moments for water to soak in. Aiming to water once a week, but can’t tell if it’s dying from the water or nutient deficiency.